Transform to a unit domain each integral in a 5-D integral.
I want to confirm if i can change the integration domains of any 5-D integral to $[[-1,1],[-1,1],[-1,1],[-1,1],[-1,1]]$ if the original domains are $[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i,j]]$, for $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j$ $\in \mathbb{R}$, doing the following:
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^f\int_g^h\int_i^j f(\color{red}{x},\color{red}{y},\color{red}{z},\color{red}{w},\color{red}{t})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t} = \\\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{f-e}{2}\right)\left(\frac{h-g}{2}\right)\left(\frac{j-i}{2}\right)\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 f(\color{red}{x'},\color{red}{y'},\color{red}{z'},\color{red}{w'},\color{red}{t'})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t},
$$
where
$$
\color{red}{x'}= \frac{j-i}{2}\color{red}{x} + \frac{j+i}{2}, \\ \color{red}{y'}= \frac{h-g}{2}\color{red}{y} + \frac{h+g}{2}, \\ \color{red}{z'}= \frac{f-e}{2}\color{red}{z} + \frac{f+e}{2}, \\ \color{red}{w'}= \frac{d-c}{2}\color{red}{w} + \frac{d+c}{2}, \\ \color{red}{t'}= \frac{b-a}{2}\color{red}{t} + \frac{b+a}{2}. \\
$$
Another question is for the case when one of the variables to be integrated has an integration domain ranging from a constant to another variable that will be integrated subsequently. What i mean is:
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^\color{red}{w}\int_g^h\int_i^j f(\color{red}{x},\color{red}{y},\color{red}{z},\color{red}{w},\color{red}{t})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t}.
$$
In this case, the integration domain in $d\color{red}{z}$ has been changed from $[e,f]$ to $[e,\color{red}{w}]$, where $\color{red}{w}$ is a variable to be integrated later. In this case, should i do:
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^\color{red}{w}\int_g^h\int_i^j f(\color{red}{x},\color{red}{y},\color{red}{z},\color{red}{w},\color{red}{t})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t} = \\\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{h-g}{2}\right)\left(\frac{j-i}{2}\right)\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{\color{red}{w}-e}{2}\right)f(\color{red}{x'},\color{red}{y'},\color{red}{z'},\color{red}{w'},\color{red}{t'})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t},
$$
with
$$
\color{red}{z'}= \frac{\color{red}{w}-e}{2}\color{red}{z} + \frac{\color{red}{w}+e}{2}
$$
or
$$
\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_e^\color{red}{w}\int_g^h\int_i^j f(\color{red}{x},\color{red}{y},\color{red}{z},\color{red}{w},\color{red}{t})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t} = \\ \left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{h-g}{2}\right)\left(\frac{j-i}{2}\right)\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\color{red}{w} + \frac{d+c}{2}\right)-e}{2}\right)f(\color{red}{x'},\color{red}{y'},\color{red}{z'},\color{red}{w'},\color{red}{t'})\, d\color{red}{x}\, d\color{red}{y} \, d\color{red}{z} \, d\color{red}{w} \,d\color{red}{t}
$$
with
$$
\color{red}{z'}= \frac{\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\color{red}{w} + \frac{d+c}{2}\right)-e}{2}\color{red}{z} + \frac{\left(\frac{d-c}{2}\color{red}{w} + \frac{d+c}{2}\right)+e}{2}?
$$

I guess you meant $[[a,b],[c,d],...,[i,j]]$ indicates $i  \le x \le j, \ldots$, (not $a \le x \le b$) and in the 2nd example $z' = [(w' - e) / 2] z + (w' + e) / 2$ (accordingly, $(w' - e) / 2$ is the factor to be multiplied to the integrand), then, yes, unless the integrals are ill-defined.
